# Laravel where / how to validate form input

Tags: validation, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm a little confused as to where / how to actually validate form input with Laravel. Someone suggested to me that I shouldn't do this in the model but should have a separate manager/repository to validate form input. Therefore, form validation and actual saving of the model are handled by two separate classes.

Yet I see people validating form input directly on the model (I just watched one of Jeffrey Way's Laracasts videos where he does exactly that).

Can anyone give me some direction, please?

Comment: I personally prefer to do it in the controller, but I'm not sure if that's the right way/best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a matter of opinion and there really is no *right answer*.

One thing that is pretty much accepted is that since you are writing an app in an MVC framework, you should probably embrace that pattern at least on some level.  MVC favors `fat models, lean controllers` and your `controller` code should be for linking the model and the views, not for application logic.  So, as a best practice, you should probably not do your form validation in the `controller`.

Now, `model` vs. `form validation class` - this one is less *certain* ;)

**model** this seems like a pretty useful place for this type of logic and I don't think you could be doing it *wrong* if you put form validation here.  As you have pointed out, respected community leaders such as Jeffrey Way show putting the form validation in the `model`

**custom validation class** some people argue (Shawn McCool for instance) that with form validation, you are not actually validating the model, per se, but the form itself and therefore the code does not belong in the `model`.  The argument is that your form logic/data could be unique to that form and not specific to the model.  For instance, your form could be inputting data from many `models` and therefore the code should remain separate.  e.g. a blog post with tags.  You are actually validating input on `posts` and `tags` and it may not make sense to process the form validation in the `Posts` model.

TL:DR - it's really a matter of how you feel you can make it work to your satisfaction.  There is no *right way*.

There is a pretty good discussion on this on the old Laravel forums:

http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1199